# Facebook Page Plug-In not responding to data-height under certain situations

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-chrome

I am playing around with the Facebook Page Plug-in and am having a heck of a time with it. What I am trying to do is set the 'data-height' attribute of the plug in to be equal to the height of another div on window load. I generated this HTML using the Facebook Page Plug-in creator:

```
    <div class="facebookHousing col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FACEBOOKPAGEURL/"
             data-tabs="timeline"
             data-width="500"
             data-small-header="true"
             data-adapt-container-width="true"
             data-hide-cover="true"
             data-show-facepile="false"
             data-height="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
var windowSize = $(window).innerWidth();

$(window).on('load', function () {

    var newsSize = $('.newsHousing').height();

    if (windowSize <= 479) {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', 250);
    }
    else if (windowSize >= 480 && windowSize <= 767) {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', 300);
    }
    else if (windowSize >= 768 && windowSize <= 991) {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', 500);
    }
    else {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', newsSize);
    }
});
```

I do most of my initial testing in Google Chrome, and to emulate different screen sizes I use the 'Toggle Device Toolbar' option. However, I am seeing very strange behavior when using this functionality.

When I have the Device Toolbar open, the jQuery works as expected. If newsSize is equal to 1200px, the height of the plugin will be set to 1200px and it renders as expected. When I close the Device Toolbar and try again, the height of the plug-in always defaults to 500 and does not respect the variable at all.

What is it about Chrome's 'Toggle Device Toolbar' that would allow the jQuery to function in a completely different manner than if it was closed? I set various breakpoints to make sure that newsSize always had a value, and I see no reason the plugin would ignore this value.

Comment: You are sure that you are changing the height before Facebook render the plugin?

Comment: So with the setup above, if I change out newsSize for 1000, the plug-in will render at 1000px height. This leads me to believe it is being set before the plugin is rendered. However, I can set up an alert in the else statement to display the newsSize value, and can see that it is 1200...and yet the plug-in is rendered at 500 regardless, if the Device Toolbar is closed. Works fine when it is open.

Comment: It is pretty wild. I can toggle the toolbar on and do a Ctrl+F5, and the plug-in is set to the expected height. If I turn the toolbar off and Ctrl+F5, it stays at 500

Comment: Just to add to this, even if I move the script that is rendering the plug-in below the portion that is setting the data-height attribute, it STILL gets set to 500 if the toolbar is closed.

Comment: _“This leads me to believe it is being set before the plugin is rendered”_ - due to the asynchronous loading of the SDK, I am pretty sure that your belief here is simply wrong. This could perhaps best be solved by setting up a function that handles both the window load event and the fbasyncinit event of the SDK, the latter set up to not automatically render social plugins, and then sets data-height and calls the render method explicitly once both events have fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBore was right, I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how this plug in was loading asynchronously. Here is what I ended up changing my code to, and now it is working:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

    var windowSize = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (windowSize <= 479) {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', 250);
        renderFacebookPlugin();
    }
    else if (windowSize >= 480 && windowSize <= 767) {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', 300);
        renderFacebookPlugin();
    }
    else if (windowSize >= 768 && windowSize <= 991) {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', 500);
        renderFacebookPlugin();
    }
    else {          
        setTimeout(function () { changeFBPagePlugin() }, 500);            
    }  
});   

renderFacebookPlugin = function () {

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}

changeFBPagePlugin = function () {

    var container_height = $('.newsHousing').height().toFixed(0);

    if (!isNaN(container_height)) {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', container_height);            
    }
    else {
        $('.fb-page').attr('data-height', 500);
    }

    renderFacebookPlugin();
}
```